# Email validator

Tags: javascript

Having troubles with my email validation code. I keep on getting the error that my function is not defined. i have made a javascript file for the java code and then i used the onchange in my html to trigger the function.

```
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" onchange="check();" />

    function check() {
email = document.getElementById("email").value;
filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (filter.test(email.value)) 
    {
    document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid green";  
    return true;
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid red";
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since when was `+` an invalid character in email addresses? And why can't a TLD have more than 4 characters in it?

Comment: +1 from me. No need to down vote. OP is asking for why getting javascript error which is not even caused by the regex.

Comment: Sorry im still not used to the way that i have to post a question

Answer (score 4):

Put your javascript in `<script>` tags.

Also rename your variable name `email` since your textbox is using it already.

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" onchange="check();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var email_x = document.getElementById("email").value;
        filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (filter.test(email.value)) {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid green";
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("email").style.border = "3px solid red";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Email validation is not always as simple as your regular expression. Have you looked at:

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

A better option would be to use [Verimail.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js). It's a simple script that takes care of it for you. With Verimail.js you could just do:

```
var email = "cool@fabeook.cmo";
var verimail = new Comfirm.AlphaMail.Verimail();

verimail.verify(email, function(status, message, suggestion){
    if(status < 0){
        // Incorrect syntax!
    }else{
        // Syntax looks great!
    }
});
```

The above example will hit the line 'Incorrect syntax!' because of the invalid TLD 'cmo'. Besides this, it will also give a suggestion that you can return to your user, in this case, the suggestion variable will contain 'cool@facebook.com' since 'fabeook.cmo' looks a lot like 'facebook.com'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for html input field and button field

```
   <input input type="text" name="txtEmailId" id="txtEmailId" /> 
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Suscribe" name="Suscribe" 
            onclick="javascript:ShowAlert()" />
```

Now add the below function to the header of your page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowAlert() {
  var email = document.getElementById('txtEmailId');
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Thanks for your intrest in us, Now you 
        will be able to receive monthly updates from us.");
        document.getElementById('txtEmailId').value = "";
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Here you can find the article on this [Email Validation in JavaScript](http://www.tapankumar.in/2013/04/email-validation-in-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are specific about the domains , you may use this code for email validation so as to prevent anonymous email domains.

```
(^([a-zA-Z]{1,20}[-_.]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})(\@gmail\.com|\@yahoo\.com|\@hotmail\.com)$)
```

You may add additional domains too.