# Regex for email confirmation

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to make sure fields are filled in. How can I add some code to make sure it's a valid email?

```
function verify() {
if ($("#ddlBusinessName").val() == "0") {
            alert("Please select the name.");
        }
        else if ($("#txtEmail").val().length <= 0 || $("#txtEmailConfirm").val().length <= 0) {
            alert("Please enter the email address and confirm the email address.");
             else if ($("#TxtPassword").val().length <=0 || $("#TxtConfirmPassword").val().length <=0) {
            alert("Please enter your password.");
        }

         }
```

**EDIT**
How can I implement this into my code though?

```
 function validateEmail(email) { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Have you searched a bit on Google?

Comment: you are never going to fully validate an email address with regular expressions. find a library that will validate it for you.

Comment: Have you searched a bit on Stackoverflow?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email+regex&submit=search

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Here's an example of a quite complete regex for email btw: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only safe way to validate an email address is actually sending an email to it. If this fails with a (permanent - graylisting errors would be temporary) error code you know the address is invalid.

Of course you cannot do that in JavaScript - so I'd limit the client-side check to a very simple check - something like `/^[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ ]+$/` (thx [@NedBatchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039595/298479)) would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674524/340736

For your client-side validation I would recommend that you use [Verimail.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js). It validates your e-mail address against a RFC 822 regular expression, but also a full list of all registered TLD's.

Answer (score 0):

Try RegExpLib [Site Reference](http://www.regexplib.com/Search.aspx?k=valid%20email%20address)

Note that you're validating the email *could* exist, not that it *does* exist!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to get too fancy with email address validation.  Try this: [Humane email validation](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200908/humane_email_validation.html).