# Email validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to validate an email using regular expresions.This is my code:

```
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>

       var email = $("input#email"),
       re =  /^[A-Za-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-][A-Za-z0-9]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/; 

       if(re.test(email.val())){
           alert("email valid");
       }else{
           alert("email not valid");
       }
```

No matter what I enter in the text field it says the email is not valid.What is the problem?

Comment: That selector looks weird. Try `$('#email')`

Comment: worksforme: http://jsfiddle.net/23Jfz/

Comment: works for me too. http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/NgqGh/

Comment: I suggest trimming of the string. For what it is worth, the regex works for me in Chrome. Can you transfer email.val() into another variable and console.log it?

Comment: Where do you run the code from? You're not setting that `email=$("input#email")` _before_ the element has been parsed are you? You don't have more than one element with that id? (Does an `alert(email.val())` just before the `if` show the entered value?)

Comment: the problem seemed to have been with the regular expression declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **Working demo** = http://jsfiddle.net/buezz/

Hope this helps your cause `:)` feel free to play around.

Good link: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/validate-email-address-using-jquery.html

**code**

```
function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btnValidate').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#txtEmail').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
​
```

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674524/340736

My recommendation to you would be, don't try to roll you're own. You'll probably do it wrong. Try to follow standards, such as RFC 822. It's not that easy to do by your self, but there are libraries that does this.

An example is [Verimail.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js). It follows RFC 822 but also does TLD validation according to the full list of TLDs registerd by IANA.

It's also simple to use:

```
var email = "cool@fabeook.cmo";
var verimail = new Comfirm.AlphaMail.Verimail();

verimail.verify(email, function(status, message, suggestion){
    if(status < 0){
        // Incorrect syntax!
    }else{
        // Syntax looks great!
    }
});
```

The above example will hit the line 'Incorrect syntax!' because of the invalid TLD 'cmo'. Besides this, it will also give a suggestion that you can return to your user, in this case, the suggestion variable will contain 'cool@facebook.com' since 'fabeook.cmo' looks a lot like 'facebook.com'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
function is_email(a){return /^([\w!.%+\-])+@([\w\-])+(?:\.[\w\-]+)+$/.test(a);}
```

for my email validation; as I recall it was from facebook's signup page a while ago.

You'd just need to do:

```
if (!is_email($('#email').val()) {
   alert('invalid email and all that');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a really weird regex.

Have a look at this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-][A-Za-z0-9]
```

This will match 1 alphanumeric letter, then a alphanumeric letter or a ./_/- and then 1 or more alphanumeric letter(s).

Try this regex from [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), which I edited a little bit.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/
```